# Periodical function call in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to perform some calculations periodically in my app, i.e. every 10 minutes. I use this:

```
vm.periodicalCheck = function () {
     //calculations
};

var intervalPromise = $interval(vm.periodicalCheck, 600000);
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () { $interval.cancel(intervalPromise); });
```

Is there any better solution from performance point of view?

Comment: Why? Are you having a problem?

Comment: Not yet. Wondering if using this solution can cause problems. In other words: is this recomended way to achieve what I described?